# Lock cells in range based on value in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a bit of an issue with a VBA code which aims to:

1. Trigger once value "X" is found in Column K
2. Paste the date in Column L on the same row
3. Lock the cell in Column K so that the same sequence can't be run in the cell by the user selecting another value and then X again, as this would overwrite the date

The current code I have is this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim blnUnlockedAllCells As Boolean

    If Target.Column = 11 And Target.Value <> "X" Then 
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf Target.Column = 11 And Target.Value = "X" Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Range("L" & ThisRow).Value = Now
            End If
    End If

    If Target.Value <> "X" Then Exit Sub

    Const RangeToLock As String = "K8:K1000"

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub


    If Not blnUnlockedAllCells Then
        Me.Cells.Locked = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Me.Range(CStr(RangeToLock)).SpecialCells(2).Locked = True
        On Error GoTo 0
        blnUnlockedAllCells = True
        Me.Protect Password:="PWD", userinterfaceonly:=True 
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(CStr(RangeToLock))) Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Target) Then Target.Locked = True
    End If

End Sub
```

It seems to lock all cells in RangeToLock that are not blank rather than the cells which are equal to "X".

Any help would be appreciated, I'm entirely open to other suggestions about how to process any of the above.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious - why not declare `RangeToLock` as a `Range`?  Also, I think it's because `SpecialCells(2)` is the non-blank cells.  You may instead have to loop through that range, and set any cells `="X"` as locked.

Comment: @BruceWayne The code was adapted from a source as I was in a rush, I did think about declaring it as a range but didn't know if it would have an impact on the rest of it. I'm still getting to grips with a lot of VBA so was unsure

Comment: Note that `Target` can contain more than one cell, so you can't use `Target.Value <> "X"` if `Target.Cells.Count > 1` without a throwing type mismatch - you need to loop over the entire `Target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I'm guessing that you're over-thinking this.

First, you seem to have the sheet locked with `UserInterfaceOnly`, which means that you don't even *have to* unlock anything at all.  Just change the `.Locked` property of the cell that you want to lock and don't mess with the protection of the sheet at all.

Second, as I mentioned in the comments, `Target` will not always be just one cell (think copy-paste).  That means you have to loop over all of the cells in `Target` individually.  It also means that you can't test for `Target.Value <> "X"` before you test `If Target.Cells.Count > 1` because you'll get a type mismatch run-time error if you get more than one cell.

Third, unless you need to process other events based on writing the timestamp in column `L`, you should disable event processing before you write the change and re-enable it afterwards.  Currently you don't have any method to prevent re-entry into the event handler.

That said, you can simplify the entire procedure to this, which is both safer and has the pleasant side effect of working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        If c.Column = 11 And c.Value = "X" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Not c.Locked Then
                c.Locked = True
                Target.Parent.Cells(c.Row, 12).Value = Now
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that this assumes the worksheet is already protected.  If it isn't, either add the one-liner `If Not Me.ProtectionMode Then Me.Protect "PWD", , , , True` to the top of the procedure or (better) in the `Worksheet_Activate()` event.

Comment: This is so helpful and is great in assisting my understanding, thank you. Works perfectly. I've tried adding in some of my own code to make a vbyesno msbox appear when entering X, asking if they want to submit the value X and to ClearContents if they say no (I can't post here due to character limits). However, it gets stuck in a cycle. Additionally, I tried setting Target.Parent.Cells(c.Row, 13).Locked = True but it didn't work. Is there a better way to lock Column M too?

I really appreciate this help, I'm actively trying to improve my knowledge in VBA.

Comment: As this directly answered my question, I'm selecting this as the correct answer. I figured out the issue with my own problem, if anyone needs that then see below answer from myself.

Answer (score 0):

For my modified request to Comintern's answer,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

PW = "PWD"

Dim iRet As Integer
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim strTitle As String

strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to set this field to X?"
strTitle = "Alert"

If Not Me.ProtectionMode Then Me.Protect PW, , , , True
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Target
    If c.Column = 11 And c.Value <> "X" Then
    Exit Sub

    ElseIf c.Column = 11 And c.Value = "X" Then

    iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)

     If iRet = vbNo Then
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:=PW
        Exit Sub

     ElseIf iRet = vbYes Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not c.Locked Then
            c.Locked = True
            Target.Parent.Cells(c.Row, 13).Value = Now
            Target.Parent.Cells(c.Row, 13).Locked = True
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any tips on how I could have simplified this or made this better are much appreciated!